# how to install postgres from source code on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I followed following steps

1. make clean
2. ./configure
3. sudo make install

shows -->

```
 PostgreSQL installation complete.
```

but if typed  psql 
says -->

```
Command 'psql' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install postgresql-client-common
Please ask your administrator.
```

I dont want to install from apt-get install want to install everything from source code only

Answer (score 1):

By default, PostgreSQL is installed in `/usr/local/pgsql`, so you would type `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql` for the command line client (but remember that you have to create and start a database cluster with `initdb` first`).

If you don't like that location, use the `prefix` option of `configure`:

```
./configure prefix=/dir/where/you/want/postgres
```

Comment: `@Laurenz Albe`How to do initdb ? It's giving following error -----> initdb: no data directory specified
You must identify the directory where the data for this database system
will reside.  Do this with either the invocation option -D or the
environment variable PGDATA

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime.html). This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `./configure` without options will install the product in  `/usr/local/` and this might not be in your `PATH`. Can you check `psql` is present in `/usr/local/bin/`? If so, you can type the full path to that or add `/usr/local/bin/` to your PATH.